# Explain the output of this C Program?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define CUBE(x) (x*x*x)

int main()
{
int a, b=3;
a = CUBE(++b);
printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
return 0;
}
```

This code returns the value of `a=150` and `b=6`. Please explain this.

I think when it executes the value of `a` will be calculated as `a=4*5*6=120` but it isn't true according to the compiler , so please explain the logic....

Comment: What compiler are you using?  If I use gcc 4.2.1 I get the result:  a=120, b=6

Comment: @Magnus: any result is possible. You could get `a=120, b=6` or you could get `potato`. It's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 9):

There's no logic, it's undefined behavior because

```
++b * ++b * ++b;
```

modifies and reads `b` 3 times with no interleaving sequence points.

Bonus: You'll see another weird behavior if you try `CUBE(1+2)`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what Luchian Grigore said (which explains why you observe this weird behavior) you should notice that this macro is *horrible*: it can cause subtle and very difficult to track-down bugs, especially when called with a statement that has side-effects (like `++b`) since this will cause the statement to execute multiple times.

You should learn three thing from this:

1. **Never** reference a macro argument more than once in a macro. While there are exceptions to this rule, you should prefer to think of it as absolute.
2. Try to **avoid** calling macros with statements that contain side-effects if possible.
3. Try to **avoid** function-like macros when possible. Use inline functions instead.

Answer (score 2):

Its [undefined behavior](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#evaluation-order) to change same variable more then once in a sequence. And because this reason you will get difference results with different compilers for your code.

By the chance I am also getting same result `a = 150 and b = 6` with my compiler.

```
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

Your macro expression  `a = CUBE(++b);`  expanses as

```
a = ++b * ++b * ++b;
```

And `b` is change more then once before end of [full expression.](http://c-faq.com/sx1/index.html#full%20expression).

But how my compiler convert this expression at low level (*may be your compiler do similarly and you can try with same technique*). for this I compiled the source C with `-S` option and I got an assembly code.

```
gcc x.c -S
```

you will get `x.s` file.

I am showing partial useful asm code (*read comments*)

<sub>Because you want to know how does `150` output, thats why I am adding my answer</sub>

```
movq    %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
subq    $16, %rsp
movl    $3, -8(%rbp)    // b =  3 

addl    $1, -8(%rbp)    // b =  4
addl    $1, -8(%rbp)    // b =  5

movl    -8(%rbp), %eax  // eax = b  
imull   -8(%rbp), %eax  // 5*5 = 25

addl    $1, -8(%rbp)    // 6  `b` become 6 and

imull   -8(%rbp), %eax  // 6 * 25 = 150 
movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)  // 150 assign to `a` become 150 

movl    $.LC0, %eax     // printf function stuff...
movl    -8(%rbp), %edx
movl    -4(%rbp), %ecx
movl    %ecx, %esi
movq    %rax, %rdi
```

On inspecting this assembly code I can understand it evaluate the expression like 
`a = 5 * 5 * 6` thus `a` becomes `150` and after three increments `b` becomes `6`.

<sub>Although different compilers produce different result but I think,  `150` cab only be evaluated this sequence for `b=3` and your expression in `5*5*6`</sub>